# Magento 2.3.1 after adding watermark product image disappears

Tags: product, product-images, magento2.3.1, watermark

I am using Magento 2.3.1. After adding watermark product images disappears. How to solve? is this frame work bug?

Comment: Did you run the commands like reindex, flush and clean after do this.?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-upload-image-watermarks-in-magento-2.html This link may help you.

Comment: No i dint run command. i added water mark and refreshed cache. when i check front end images were missing. ok will go through link which you have shared. thanks.

Comment: Ok no worries do it and check.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`php bin/magento catalog:image:resize`

When I change my watermark, I need to run that or I get a 404 error on all of my images.

Comment: Thanks. I had solved it with some external help using same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the commands after you save configurations or Product.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: I tried reindex, cache clean and cache flush. unfortunately still not working.